# Why doesn't my c code work using pointer and struct?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, structure

Why doens't it work? There exists address access error. However, I tried to find the problem all over the internet and google, I coudln't. I am doing my assignment. My assistant require us to use

```
STUDENT ** list  and Malloc ()
```

However they don't explain perfectly, So I m in hard time. How can I solve this problem? Why am I getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are *required* to use `STUDENT **list` although that is not the best way to do the job. But seeing as this is an exercise I will stay with it, and `STUDENT **list` will be an array of pointers to that `struct`.

Your program has two major faults.

- Not allocating memory for each element of the pointer array
- Assigning input data to a local `struct` which is forgotten on
  function exit.

The first of those two is deadly when you try to print the data, because you use uninitialised pointers.

There are other things too which you should always check

- the value returned by `malloc`
- the result of the `scanf` functions (the value *returned* by `scanf`)

Also, you must

- restrict string input from overflowing
- `free` the memory after use

Here is a basic fix of the code, which still needs the other improvements mentioned.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ID_LEN 7
#define NAME_LEN 10

typedef struct{
    char id[ID_LEN];
    char name[NAME_LEN];
    int math;
    int eng;
} STUDENT;

void SHOW(STUDENT* list) {
    printf("ID : %s\n", list->id);
    printf("name : %s\n", list->name);
    printf("math : %d\n", list->math);
    printf("eng : %d\n", list->eng);
}

void FirstList(STUDENT *list){
    printf("ID : ");
    scanf("%s", list->id);                  // use the pointer passed
    printf("Name : ");                      // instead of local struct
    scanf("%s", list->name);
    printf("Math score: ");
    scanf("%d",&list->math);
    printf("English score: ");
    scanf("%d",&list->eng);
}

int main(){
    STUDENT **list = NULL;
    int num = 0;
    printf("How many student? ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    list = malloc(num * sizeof(STUDENT*));
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++) {
        list[i] = malloc(sizeof(STUDENT));  // allocate memory for struct
        FirstList(list[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<num; i++) {
        SHOW(list[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer, I have a more question. Then Where I should put free() code ?.... Could you help me one more time ?:)

Comment: At the end of the program. You should `free` what the array elements point to in a loop, followed by a `free` of the array itself - the reverse of what was done to `malloc` the memory.